# Is it possible to use pthread conditon variable (pthread_mutex and pthread_cond_t )with multiple conditons?

Tags: c, pthreads, race-condition

I have a multithreaded program and eacch thread focuses on its own work.  When a thread finishes its work, it will drive the event to the main thread.

So I want to use the pthread condition variable to implement the idea (i.e. pthread_cond_t and pthread_mutex_t).  The data structure will be like:

```
typedef struct peer_info {
    int ip; 
    int port;
    pthread_mutex_t peer_mutex;
    pthread_cond_t peer_cond;
    bool write_v;
    bool read_v;
    bool create_v;
    bool destroy_v;
} peer_info;
```

Suppose that:
thread1 changes the write_v and signals main thread,
thread2 changes the read_v and signals the main thread,
thread3 changes the create_v and signals the main thread,
thread4 changes the destroy_v and signals the main thread.

Is it possible to use only one pthread_mutex and pthread_cond_t to implement the above scenario? Will it cause a deadlock?

Comment: Are the `bool` flags set only once?  Does the _main_ thread clear them, or do the worker threads clear them?

Comment: @pilcrow the worker thread will change the flag and send the signal to the main thread, then the main thread clear the flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can safely wait on a "compound predicate," where one signal means "this state changed *or* that state changed *or* some other state changed *or* ..."

In your case, those states are the *`event_v`* flags you set.  Presuming your main thread is in a loop, and that the *`event_v`* flags are initialized to `false`, it'd look something like this:

```
// main loop:
pthread_mutex_lock(&pi.peer_mutex);
while (! (pi.write_v || pi.read_v || ... )) {
  pthread_cond_wait(&pi.peer_cond, &pi.peer_mutex);
}
if (pi.write_v) {
  pi.write_v = false; // clear this so we're not confused next time we wake up
  handle_write_event(&pi);
}
if (pi.read_v) {
  pi.read_v = false;
  handle_read_event(&pi);
}
if (...) ...          // handle other events
```

Note that this will handle events while the mutex is locked, which may or may not be OK for you.

As an aside, I find all those boolean flags a bit cumbersome, and might use bit flags instead:

```
#define PEER_EVENT_READ  1 << 0
#define PEER_EVENT_WRITE 1 << 1
#define PEER_EVENT_ ...

struct peer_info {
  short events_pending; // initialized to zero
  ...
};
```

So that I could concisely write:

```
while (! pi.events_pending) {
  pthread_cond_wait(&pi.peer_cond, &pi.peer_mutex);
}
if (pi.events_pending & PEER_EVENT_READ) { ... }
if ....
pi.events_pending = 0; // clear them all
```

But it's semantically the same thing, so up to you.

Comment: Thanks @pilcrow. I will take your advice using the second the choice. It's more clean:).